# Searching on Index with only two characters or less characters in search string in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb-2.1

I am using **Orient DB 2.1.16**. I have a vertex class in orientDB called **person**, I also created a property for person class called **name**. I added a full text index on that property called **person.name**. I have a **person** type vertex where **name** property equals 'abcd'. When searching on index with query `SELECT FROM INDEX:person.name WHERE KEY CONTAINSTEXT 'abc'` I get correct resultset but when I search on the same index with only two characters I get no result back `SELECT FROM INDEX:person.name WHERE KEY CONTAINSTEXT 'ab'`.I don't understand why searching with on two characters does not return any results.

Comment: Even if 2.1.16 is very old and EOL, you can use lucene full text indexes. Take a look at the documentation : http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1.x/Full-Text-Index.html